# Can't fetch a single item from an API with React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm consuming an API with React Native and I'm trying to set one item to display it's attributes but I can't get the object from the API.

This is the code I'm using, which was working perfectly when I was working with arrays of objects from the same API.

```
const url = `https://2bgo6ptw6j.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/client/99a00a42-cbc8-43e7-9b43-14b98684540f`
    const [client, setClient] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('asd');
      fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
          setClient(json);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          })
  }, []);
    const male = "Masculino";
    const female = "Femenino";
    let message;

    if (client.gender === 'M') {
      message = male;
    } else {
      message = female;
    }
```

And this is the object that is returned from that URL:

```
{
"clientName":"Diego",
"lastName":"Penaranda",
"SK":"#METADATA#99a00a42-cbc8-43e7-9b43-14b98684540f",
"PK":"CLIENT#99a00a42-cbc8-43e7-9b43-14b98684540f",
"phone":76948002,
"clientId":"99a00a42-cbc8-43e7-9b43-14b98684540f",
"gender":"M",
"type":"client"
}
```

I don't even recieve the console logs inside the useEffect, I directly get this message:
"Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined."

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference `client.gender` before the `client` is even set: On first render, `client` will be `undefined` while the fetch is happening. Only after the fetch completes will the `client` be set to an object. So you need to check if `client !== undefined` before trying to access any properties you think the result should have.

A tip: Get good at reading and understanding common error messages like this. "Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined." is a helpful error message because it's *exactly* what's happening, so if you understood the error message, I'm sure you wouldn't have needed to post this question :).

Comment: To add to this, if it worked fine with an array then probably your initial state was an empty array.  Here `const [client, setClient] = useState();` your `client` starts out as `undefined` and will stay `undefined` until the fetch is completed.  That happens asynchronously, so code below the `useEffect` will be run before the effect is completed.